# Flex - How to get the parent of a custom grid column filter editor and open a pop up window?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, popupwindow

I am trying to figure out how to open a pop up window in my Air application, in a secondary Window, instead of the main application window.

I am using the ReusableFX components, which include a custom DataGrid with filtering and other capabilities.   The filtering feature displays a pop up window via PopUpManager when you click on the top of a column in the grid.

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp(this, FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as DisplayObject);
```

The problem is that the pop up window opens in the main application - I am assuming because of the 'topLevelApplication' reference.

So, I need a way to open this window in the current Air "s:Window".

I am assuming I need a way to walk up :  this.parent.parent  or this.owner.owner - though I have tried that and it did not seem to work (it said null reference).

OR, is there a way to get the current top most window / component (NOT the main application / window)?

Update:
  I decided to create a new project for the component, and add in the Air libraries.   Now I am able to access the "NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow" call.   That gives me the correct Air window.  However, it does not seem to be working:

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp(this, NativeApplication.nativeApplication.activeWindow as DisplayObject);
```

My popup does not appear.   I am assuming because "activeWindow" is not actually a DisplayObject?     (so how do I get the DisplayObject if that's the case?)

Update:
 Could it be that I am a victim of [this adobe bug?](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-12565)  ([found here originally](http://jimmyflex.blogspot.com/2008/06/popupmanager-doesnt-work-in-air-windows.html))

Answer (score 0):

Well, I came up with some changes that seem to work, though there is probably a much cleaner way to do this - I was just not able to figure a way to get a reference to the current air application window except this way (this is using the ReuableFX custom flex component by the way):

First, in my custom DataGridColumn component, I added a public property

```
public var pApp:Object;
```

Next, I modified the DropDownFilterHeaderRenderer (extends HBox , implements IListItemRenderer), showFilterDropDown method and right before it calls dropDown.startEdit(column); , added:

```
column.pApp = parentApplication;
```

Finally, I modified DropDownFilterEditor (which extends FilterEditorBase), the method startEdit(column:MDataGridColumn)  (the previous PopUpManager was calling FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication, which is not the correct window when opening a s:Window in an Air native application:

```
var editorInstance:Object = _editor.parent;
var columnInstance:Object = editorInstance.column;
var parAppInstance:Object = columnInstance.pApp;
PopUpManager.addPopUp(this, parAppInstance as DisplayObject);
```